# Ionic + Angular Google Maps (AGM) error on touch

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, angular-google-maps

I have successfully installed angular google maps (AGM) package in my ionic application.

The map is displaying and working correctly, but there is one problem,
whenever I touch a map on the phone (Android) I am getting errors in the console.
This does not affect any usability, everything is working, but I don't wont the erros to appear, what is the problem? How to fix it? Search on Google didn't help me.

Here is the error message:
`[Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.`

Comment: did you solve the issue? I have a very similar problem

Answer (score -1):

Its only a warning but i had this problem and all I had to do is return true from touchend and the warning went away.

Comment: It's an error, because the text is red, but not orange.
I print the map using <agm-map></agm-map> tag. There is no special code in the .ts files, so there is nothing to return.